# Composite C1 4.0 Beta and MVC Player outputting 2nd html and body tags

Tags: c1-cms

I have setup and installed the Composite C1 4.0 beta, along with the latest MVC Player build (from 12/7/2012 nightly), but whenever I call the MVCPlayer function, it outputs additional  tags on the page.  For example, I am calling a MVCPlayer function for breadcrums.  This is the output:

```
..... before breadcrum content .....
<a name="site-nav" class="screen-reader"></a>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head />
    <body>
        <html>
            <head />
            <body>
<!-- START BREADCRUM SECTION -->
                <ul id="breadcrumbs">
                    <li><a href="/">Homep</a></li>
                    <li>Events</li>
                </ul>
<!-- END BREADCRUM SECTION -->
            </body>
        </html>
    </body>
</html>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
..... rest of page .....
```

As you can see, it is in the middle of the page.  The MVCPlayer is returning an XDocument in the render function.  So, how do I get rid of the extra tags before the START & END BREADCRUM SECTION comments?  The page renders fine, but this is impacting the ability for me to use a page filter to add additional content to the output, such as switching out image tag src's so I can use a jquery script to perform lazy loading images (see http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Chad

---

The output of the actual breadcrums page is simply `<ul><li>...</li></ul>`, and there are no errors in the log files.  The MVC Player actually adds the additional code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head />
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the Player.cs file, here is the code:

```
var sbHtml = new StringBuilder();
            sbHtml
                .Append(@"<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml""> 
            <head/>
            <body>")
                .Append(responseWriter.ToString())
                .Append(@"
            </body>
            </html>");

            try
            {
                return XDocument.Parse(sbHtml.ToString());
            }
```

I was able to modify the /Renderers/Page.aspx.cs and changed this line to "strip" out the extra tags:

Original:

```
xhtml = _renderingContext.FormatXhtml(xhtml);
```

Updated:

```
xhtml = _renderingContext.FormatXhtml(xhtml.Replace(@"<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">", "").Replace("<html>", "").Replace("<head />", "").Replace("<head></head>", "").Replace("<body>", "").Replace("</body>", "").Replace("</html>", ""));
```

I'm sure there is a better solution than this?  :)

Chad

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the issue but couldn't so far. I:

 1. Installed the latest 4.0 via Web Platform Installer and installed a
 2. Installed MVC Player 1.2.18
 3. Created /Views/Home/Index.ascx and Index.ascx.cs (dummy)
 4. Created /App_Code/Controllers/HomeController.cs
 5. Edited a page and inserted the Composite.AspNet.MvcPlayer function.
 6. Specified /Home in the Path parameter.
 7. Saved and published the page, viewed it in the browser.
 8. Opened and checked its Source view in the browser.

Could you please see what I should do different to be able to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that somewhere else on the the page you have markup which makes the whole result document and invalid XHTML, and therefore the system cannot process it correctly.

Try to

a) Check the log files to see if there any related warnings

b) validate the output xhtml http://www.xmlvalidation.com/